# Tax return if worked partially in the UK and partially in Germany

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, germany

I have worked from Jan to July 2015 in the UK and from Oct. to Dec. 2015 in Germany. I'm not sure if it makes sense for me to submit a tax return claim. (The tax year in the UK runs from April to April; in Germany - from January to January).

My main concern is that in the UK I was paying 20% in taxes from my brutto (all taxes together amounted to 20%). Whilst in Germany it's 40%. Thus, I'm afraid that by submitting such a claim in hope to get a couple of 100' EUR back (since I was out of work for 2,5 months, not claiming any unemployment money) I may actually myself owe to the state, since I would be submitting the claim in Germany where I would have paid twice as many taxes had I worked in Germany from the beginning of the year.

Are my concerns justifiable?

Comment: I think you have little choice - if you are required to file a country, you are _legally required_, it's not your choosing. And if you are _not_ required to, you probably paid more than you have to, and just forfeit the reimbursement by not filing.

Comment: Under some circumstances it is optional to submit a tax return - often when you have earned below some threshold of income, or resided less than some minimum time in a country. It might well be optional for a few months in Germany, but I don't know.

Comment: Yes, it is optional for me. But since I don't know if I'm entitled to a tax return or not, I'm afraid to get into a situation where "after investigating my circumstances" the Germans conclude that I've paid too little rather than too much!